# Formatting with toString so that I get a chart of sorts

Tags: c#, java, formatting, tostring

I'm attemping to make make a toString method that formats like the following:

```
10001 Lumia 900        3     $450.00   $1350.00
```

This needs to format like this with different length strings when I iterate over an arraylist of custom objects with an: `int`, `string`, `int`, `double`, `double`.

However I have no idea how to format a returned string so that it always looks like this, every thing in it's own little column.  Also not sure how to chage the standard double format from `0.0` to `0.00`.,

The best I have come up with is this:

```
return "\t" + this.item.getSKU()+ "\t" + this.item.getDesc() +"\t\t" + 
this.getQuantity() + "\t" + this.item.getPrice() + "\t" + 
this.getExtensionPrice();
```

It now formats correctly but I'm still not sure how to  get the `double` to format with 2 decimal places.

Comment: I figured out the formatting problem.  need to use `String.format("%.2f", price)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Consistent Whitespace

You might avoid using regular whitespace and use a tab delimiter, `\t`.

```
return "SKU:\t" + this.item.getSKU() + "\t\t" + "Price:\t" + this.item.getPrice();
```

(edit...)

Alternatively, you may need to resort to padding values so that they have a consistent
width. For example, you many need to take $20.00 and pad this with whitespace so that 
it aligns with the largest lengthed value ($4000.00).

```
price:  __$20.00
price:  $4000.00
```

...where the underscore represents the added whitespace.

This could be achieved by first loopping though all of the elements and 
finding the longest length for all of an elements subgroups. Once you have 
the largest known length you could pad the remaining elements with the 
difference.

#### Rounding Decimal Places

```
inputValue = Math.Round(inputValue, 2);
```

Comment: won't tabs not work if a string is smaller or longer than the 8 character boundary? (or however long your tabs render as)

Comment: yes. see explanation involving adding padding. there may be third party solutions available for this problem, I'm not sure though.

Comment: I just figured depending on the size of the number pad it otherwise just ignore it.  Also, Math.round doesn't work here only rounds it up and it doesn't accept 2 incoming parms.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
this.item.getPrice().ToString("$#,0.00");
```

Custom Numeric Format Strings

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx